# How to Unroot " Galaxy tab 2 p3113 8gb wifi "

Tags: restore, unrooting, samsung-galaxy-tab-2-7

My 9 year old son rooted his tab on his own, against my wishes. **I tried** a factory restore and used *Kies* to load via PC although this did not restore the tab.

**It's still showing as rooted**. Can anyone help as it seems he should have installed software prior to rooting from what I have read. Is there anything I can do to restore it to factory-defaults? Please anyone who can give suggestion I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Just reinstalling factory ROM will remove root access. I am assuming he has a custom recovery image installed? Also, how exactly is it showing that its rooted? Is a superuser app installed? Stock ROM?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend doing a nandroid backup before messing around with it too much. If you have a custom recovery installed, such as TWRP, you could download the stock ROM of your specific model (or really, any rom you wanted), and flash it via custom recovery. I highly suggest backing up prior. Once you do this everything should go back to how it would be if it was a brand new phone (besides the custom recovery - but this is more beneficial than problematic.)